# Make class return different type

Tags: c#, class, oop

I want to create a simple `DbContext` class to avoid repetitive code in my repositories. The problem is that I don't know how to make it initialize/configure itself in constructor and then return itself. I only know how to assign additional property in that class and then call it.

I'm not sure how to properly articulate my problem so feel free to edit, however I think it will be very clear if you look at the code.

As you can see I'm calling `.GetDatabase` on every query, what I want is to remove `.GetDatabase` and make `_db` return what `.GetDatabase` is returning.

**DbContext**

```
public class DbContext
{
    public DbContext()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var server = client.GetServer();
        this.GetDatabase = server.GetDatabase("test");
    }

    public MongoDatabase GetDatabase { get; private set; }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public class AdministratorRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext _db = new DbContext();

    public Administrator GetByUsername(string username)
    {
        return _db.GetDatabase // I want to remove this .GetDatabase and make my _db itself return database
            .GetCollection<Administrator>("administrators")
            .FindOne(Query<Administrator>.EQ(x => x.Username, username));
    }
}
```

Comment: unless you make your `DbContext` inherit from `MongoDatabase`

Comment: I'd recommend renaming your `DbContext` class to something else - there's already a class with that name in EntityFramework. Even though there's no conflict there, I'd still avoid creating a class name that matches a common framework name just for clarity.

Comment: @JoeEnos I don't use EntityFramework in this project so I think it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add one method to the `DbContext` class:

```
public ?? GetCollection<T>(string collection)
{
    return _db.GetCollection<T>(collection);
}
```

I think the type is `MongoCollection`, but I'm not certain on that. Now you can do this:

```
return _db.GetCollection<Administrator>("administrators")
        .FindOne(Query<Administrator>.EQ(x => x.Username, username));
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is looking for. 'make _db return what .GetDatabase is returning.'

Comment: Indeed. just trying to be strict.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `DbContext` is only a wrapper you're using to initialize `MongoDatabase`, try this:

```
public class DbContext
{
    public static MongoDatabase GetDatabase()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var server = client.GetServer();

        return server.GetDatabase("test");
    }
}
```

Then in client code:

```
private readonly MongoDatabase _db = DbContext.GetDatabase();
```

Also, you better pass the connection-string and database name as a parameter and avoid hard-coding it in the method.